# How do I remove a Posgresql image from a Docker container and install a new one

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and loveing it for the most part. The one thing I DON'T love is replacing a DB. I have a Vue/Django app that I borked the database on. I need to re run the migrations. It's a special case where I need to rebuild the DB for a user account.

Regardless, I can't seem to do it. I've followed the instructions here (https://github.com/Radu-Raicea/Dockerized-Flask/wiki/%5BDocker%5D-Remove-all-Docker-volumes-to-delete-the-database) and it looks like it works in that it lists what is removed. But then it doesn't seem to actually remove it.

What I want to do is just switch to a new database in the container for Postgresql.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a little confused by what you're trying to do; in part because the underlying image is an immutable property of a container, you intrinsically can't change the image under a running container.  If you stop the old container, delete it, and start a new container with a new image and the same name, does that have the effect you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think it's a docker issue.
2. If I understand you correctly, you just want to wipe out the existing db and recreate it with migrations. If so, all you have to do is manually(or write a
   script to) wipe out the db.
3. You can use a db in a container in dev environment, but usually not for production.